# What is the best text editor for bidi texts?

Tags: editors, bidi, xepersian

I want to write latex in both Latin as well as Persian using TeXLive and 
    xepersian 
package. I have experiences with Texstudio but I need an editor which avoids two problems:

1-crazy cursor: when a Persian paragraph is longer than a single line of the editor (Texstudio in my case) then the location that the cursor is shown is not the accurate location of it (the cursor is shown one character after its true location).

2- messy order of characters: When both Persian texts and commands/LTR texts are present in the same line the order of appearance for the characters for command/LTR is shuffled annoyingly. an example:

```
با جای‌گذاری رابطه  (\ref{GDP}) در رابطه (\ref{GNDI}) خواهیم داشت:
```

Comment: i think this topic is too broad, as you can use any editor you like to type your documents and use the compiling engine seperately. you have to figure out, which one you like best and what your method of development is. of course, you can get a couple of suggestions, but overall the answers don't narrow down to your particular situation. therefore I vote for closing this question

Comment: @naphaneal I edited the question to show that I look for an editor that avoids two specific problem when typesetting Persian.

Comment: I'm not sure what can be added beyond the 'big list' IDE question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides. Beyond 'yes, it supports RTL' things are subjective.

Comment: I use GNU Emacs 25 for Arabic.  One does need to be more heavily caffeinated than usual in order to keep track of the cursor, but it’s reliable.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bidirectional-Editing.html#Bidirectional-Editing  You may also be interested in https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36774/designing-bidi-text-editing

Comment: https://andreasmhallberg.github.io/typing-arabic-in-vim/ may be useful to you.